# Where can I find documentation on custom event objects in polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I noticed that some demos of custom events show something like

```
this.fire("myEvent", {message: "My custom event fired"});
```

And then a listener will call a function that gets the event object like

```
myFunction: function(e){
 console.log(e.detail.message);
}
```

How come I can't just do e.message? Where did the detail come from? I made a test custom event and fired it and just console logged e, and I got the following object

```
bubbles:true
cancelBubble:false
cancelable:false
composed:false
currentTarget:null
defaultPrevented:false
detail:Object
eventPhase:0
isTrusted:false
path:Array[7]
returnValue:true
srcElement:lala-element
target:lala-element
timeStamp:4848.3150000000005
type:"waiting"
__proto__:Event
```

So where did all of this come from, and where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1):

> How come I can't just do `e.message`? Where did the `detail` come from?

That's part of the [DOM spec for `CustomEvent`](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-customevent). I assume the user-provided `detail` is encapsulated in the event's `detail` field to cleanly separate the user's data from the event's own metadata.

> So where did all of this come from, and where can I read about it?

The API for `CustomEvent` can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent).

Comment: @BobbyBattista No problem